# Error conectar base de datos MySQL con Java

Tags: java, mysql, base-de-datos

Estaba haciendo una app de control de stock e inventario para un comercio. Sin embargo, estoy teniendo problemas para hacer la parte del *Login*, ya que no se conecta con la base de datos.

Quisiera saber donde es que me estoy equivocando, les adjunto el código. Gracias de antemano.

```java
////////////////   vendedorDAO.java //////////////
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class VendedorDAO {
    PreparedStatement ps;
    ResultSet rs;

    Conexion acceso=new Conexion();
    Connection con;

    public EntidadVendedor ValidarVendedor(String dni,String user){
        EntidadVendedor ev=new EntidadVendedor();
        String sql="select * from vendedor where Dni=? and User=?";
        try {
            con=acceso.Conectar();
            ps=con.prepareStatement(sql);
            ps.setString(1, dni);
            ps.setString(2, user);
            rs=ps.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
            ev.setId(rs.getInt(1));
            ev.setDni(rs.getString(2));
            ev.setNom(rs.getString(3));
            ev.setTel(rs.getString(4));
            ev.setEstado(rs.getString(5));
            ev.setUser(rs.getString(6));
        }
        catch (Exception e) { }
        return ev;
    }
}
```

```java
////////////////   conexion.java //////////////
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class Conexion {
    Connection con;
    String url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bd_ventas";
    String user="root";
    String pass="12345678";
    public Connection Conectar(){
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            con=DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,pass);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return con;

    }
}
```

No se si falta algo, yo ahí puse todo lo que vi en un curso.

Comment: Hola, realmente desde mis conocimientos no sé si sea lo siguiente:
`String sql="select * from vendedor where Dni=+dni+ and User=+user+";` Esto para que capture los datos de los parámetros que estas pasando.

Comment: No lo se, probe cambiando cosas de ahi y nada

Comment: @MatiasCaballero nunca pero nunca dejes los los `try catch` sin la impresiono del error `(Exception e) { } ` lo mínimo es `(Exception e) {e.printStackTrace()};` agregar el `printStackTrace` , si no colocas la impresión del error tu programa falla y nunca sabrás porque. Cunado tengas la traza del error actualiza tu  pregunta agregando la traza y asi podremos darte un solución más exacta.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class VendedorDAO {
//No te olvides de encapsular los atributos.
private PreparedStatement ps;
private ResultSet rs;    
private Conexion acceso;
private Connection con;

public VendedorDAO(){
  //lo dejo adentro del constructor para que hagas una nueva conexion cuando
  //instancias a VendedorDAO, sino cada vez que lo llamas crea una nueva.
  acceso=new Conexion();
}

public EntidadVendedor ValidarVendedor(String dni,String user){
    EntidadVendedor ev=new EntidadVendedor();
    String sql="select * from vendedor where Dni=? and User=?";
    try {
       con=acceso.Conectar();
       ps=con.prepareStatement(sql);
       ps.setString(1, dni);
       ps.setString(2, user);
       rs=ps.executeQuery();
        //aca en vez de while pone un if, pq se supone que hay un solo
        //usuario con esos datos
        if (rs.next()) {
            ev.setId(rs.getInt(1));
            ev.setDni(rs.getString(2));
            ev.setNom(rs.getString(3));
            ev.setTel(rs.getString(4));
            ev.setEstado(rs.getString(5));
            ev.setUser(rs.getString(6));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    return ev;
}
```

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, cambie el código como esta acá pero igual sigo sin poder solucionarlo, me estoy volviendo loco 

Comment: Lanza algún error?, que puedas subir así lo vemos?

Comment: Error en si no, pero cuando intento acceder con el usuario y contraseña que esta en la base de datos, no me deja acceder. Dice 'usuario invalido', como esta programado

Comment: donde estas comparando EntidadVendedor que devuelve?, osea, este codigo devuelve un EntidadVendedor con el dni y el usuario, donde comparas al EntidadVendedor con los datos del formulario de ingreso?

Comment: Hay una clase que se llama "EntidadVendedor", contiene los datos del usuario vendedor, por ejemplo:  String dni;
    String nom;
    String tel;
    String estado;
    String user;

Comment: Despues estan los mismos datos, en public EntidadVendedor(int id, String dni, String nom, String tel, String estado, String user) {
        this.id = id;
        this.dni = dni;
        this.nom = nom;
        this.tel = tel;
        this.estado = estado;
        this.user = user;
    }

y luego un return de los mismos datos

Comment: claro, con ValidarVendedor vos llenas en el caso de que este en la base alguien con el dni y usuario que pedis; ahora tenes que tener una clase que llame a ValidarVendedor, en la que te aparece el cartel 'usuario invalido', la podes agregar al codigo que pusiste?

Comment: Al final era todo un problema de versiones, después de días lo pude solucionar. Gracias por la ayuda!!

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el error es en la consulta, probé como lo tienes y no me genera ningún error, pero tampoco hace nada al consultar en la base de datos.
Lo modifiqué en esta línea:

```
String sql="select * from vendedor where Dni=? and User=?";
```

y reemplacé el = por un LIKE.

```
String sql="SELECT * FROM vendedor WHERE Dni LIKE ? and User LIKE ?";
```

y funcionó perfecto.

Ya que son de tipo `string`, si fueran valores numéricos funcionarían perfecto con el =.